# A player's character stole from another PC, leading to a conflict. As a DM, what can I do?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, problem-players, online-roleplaying

I am the DM for an online Evil campaign for D&D.  The players just found the *Book of Vile Darkness* however one of my players decided to pickpocket the book from the player who had found it and had claimed it.

My problem now is that because of this the victim is upset having just received it after much time spent searching, only to have it stolen by another player.  The player who stole it claims that they did it for character reasons and has locked it completely out of the victims reach.

I am not certain as to how to proceed with this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Is the problem that the player whose PC was the victim is upset? Is the problem that the item isn't in the "right" PC's hands? Is the problem that one PC stole from another PC? Don't just say *Yes!* as the site needs a specific problem to solve. Pick the biggest one, and edit this question to be about that. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: I would consider updating the title to read "a character stole from another character", just to make it more clear what this is about.

Comment: This is still pretty unclear. The entire question could do to be revised (by the author) with a careful look at the use of "character" versus "player". It could use some paragraph breaks too - it's tough to read and interpret when formatted as a wall of text.

Comment: Was inter-player combat or harm explicitly addressed in the application form?

Comment: No, Inter player harm/combat was not mentioned nor intended.

Comment: The problem at this point is between the two players. The victim is not even necessarily mad at losing that specific item more so that the other player would steal it for no particular reasons other than its for character reasons.

Comment: Related, see: [My Guy Syndrome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it)

Comment: When one participant wants to advance at the expense of another, and the second is unwilling, that's a problem with expectations. You seem to have a no PVP setting, but you allowed PVP. Have you asked the group about PVP activity, and if they want to allow it?

Comment: How did the player-victim learn that the player-thief robbed his PC? That is, the circumstances surrounding this scenario are a little vague. For example, did the thief-player communicate to you privately that his PC was stealing the book then his PC committed the theft then you told the victim-player that his PC's book was missing and that the other PC had stolen it? It's difficult to suggest a course of action when readers don't know the course of action that led you to this point!

Comment: Also, please include a tag to indicate which edition of D&D this is for. [tag:dnd-5e]? [tag:dnd-4e]? [tag:dnd-3.5e]? etc.

Comment: What is generally accepted at your table? Is PvP or inter-character conflict a regular part of the game? How do you feel about the situation, do you have a preferred outcome? Is the theft itself something you want to avoid in the future or do you just want a technique for solving it when it does? All of this information will help us to give you a better answer